# Continuous creation of bitmaps leads to memory leak

Tags: c#, memory, bitmap, memory-leaks

I have a thread that continuously generates bitmaps and takes a screenshot of another program's window. Now, I have a pictureBox on my form, and that's constantly being updated with the bitmaps generated. Here's the code I have in the thread:

```
        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        while (true)
        {
            if (listBoxIndex != -1)
            {
                Rectangle rect = windowRects[listBoxIndex];
                bitmap = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
                IntPtr hdc = g.GetHdc();
                PrintWindow(windows[listBoxIndex], hdc, 0);
                pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
                g.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
            }
        }
```

As you can see, this leads to a memory leak, because of the continuous call to new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height). I've tried adding "bitmap.Dispose()" to the bottom of the while loop, but that leads to the pictureBox's image also being disposed, which makes a giant red X in place of the actual image. Is there any way I can dispose of "bitmap" without disposing of the pictureBox image?

Answer (score 10):

You're also "leaking" the Graphics object. Try this:

```
    while (true)
    {
        if (listBoxIndex != -1)
        {
            Rectangle rect = windowRects[listBoxIndex];
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                IntPtr hdc = g.GetHdc();
                try
                {
                    PrintWindow(windows[listBoxIndex], hdc, 0);
                }
                finally
                {
                    g.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
                }
            }
            if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
            }
            pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh that's right. How did the using keyword slip my mind? I've modified my code. Thanks!

Comment: `using` the bitmap will dispose it after assigning it to your `PictureBox`, which is what causes the bitmap to become unaccessible in the first place. You need to keep the bitmap alive for the duration of it's display on the `PictureBox`.

Comment: @xmenW.K. What exactly is not true? `Image.Dispose()` releases the native image pointer, you can check the source yourself.

Comment: opps I forgot to delete that comment. Sorry ;)

Comment: In my case `Bitmap.Dispose()` and `using Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(Bitmap)` eliminated memory leak. Could you say why in case `Graphics g` declared as class member and instantiating it like `g = Graphics.FromImage(Bitmap); g.Dispose()` does not release memory?

Answer (score 1):

The answered example has a leak with Graphics g
after `g.ReleaseHdc(..);`

Remember to dipose the graphics variable

as for example:

```
g.Dispose();
```

Comment: This isn't right. He is disposing, the "g" is in a "using" part, which automaticlly calls "dispose" in the end.