# Will below code cause memory leak?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I want to create a memory leak by using C#, so I write the following code try to create one. The concept is to write a explicit Dispose which do nothing but call  GC.SuppressFinalize() to prevent the GC's work. But it seams like the memory doesn't leak when I was running the code. Can anyone help to tell me why?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var t = new Foo();
            t.create_leak();
            t.Dispose();
        }
    }        
}
class Foo:IDisposable
{
    public void create_leak() {
        m_value = new int[10000];
        Console.WriteLine(m_value[10].ToString()+DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }

    public void Dispose() { GC.SuppressFinalize(this); }

    private int[] m_value;

    ~Foo() { }
}
```

Comment: I am really struggling to process your title... "correct way to create memory leak", its making me feel a little dizzy actually

Comment: @musefan, glad it's not just me!

Comment: Why would you want to deliberately create a memory leak? The only reason I can think of for people deliberately causing them is for hacking purposes.

Comment: @DavidArno it's just an interview question, not for hacking:)

Comment: @musefan sorry for the title, i have changed it:) is it any better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The concept is to write a explicit Dispose which do nothing but call GC.SuppressFinalize() to prevent the GC's work.

`GC.SuppressFinalize` doesn’t prevent the GC’s work. It merely prevents the GC from calling the finalizer on your object. But managed memory is still going to be reclaimed. If you want to create a memory leak, then you need to allocate unmanaged memory or allocate managed memory in such a fashion that it cannot be reclaimed (because it remains referenced indefinitely). [String interning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx) is one such way. Compiled regular expressions is another (however, that memory will of course still be reclaimed once your process terminates).

Comment: GC never ever calls `Dispose`; it prevents the GC from calling `~Foo()`

Comment: Well, `SuppressFinalize` doesn't prevent `Dispose being called, it prevent that if the finaliser calls it.

Comment: @Marc Yes, I just noticed that myself.

Comment: Create a static collection of `Font`s and just leave them there! A million should do it!... although it's not technically a memory leak if you do it on purpose

Comment: @musefan Doesn’t even have to be static, local will do. But it’s arguable whether this is a leak – it’s just exhausting the memory, not *leaking* it.

Comment: @musefan that still isn't a "leak" though - depending on how you define "leak", of course

Comment: yeah I edited that in after thinking about it myself. I know what you guys are getting at anyway

Answer (score 3):

That isn't a leak, because each `Foo` is still eligible for collection at the end of each loop; the `SuppressFinalize` just means that `~Foo()` will not be called - it doesn't change the fact that each `m_value` is eligible for collection.

It is pretty hard to get a genuine leak. If you just want to fill memory, keep all the `Foo` instances in a `List<T>` or similar - then they will never be eligible for collection. For a genuine leak, you might want to allocate unmanaged memory - perhaps `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use objects like "Bitmaps" or "Fonts" to generate the memory leak. These objects requires you to explicitly dispose it as otherwise could cause a memory leak. An example can be found here:

[Continuous creation of bitmaps leads to memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918518/continuous-creation-of-bitmaps-leads-to-memory-leak)

Comment: Actually, the issue there is not a memory leak: `Image` etc have finalizers, and would eventually both the managed and unmanaged components would be correctly deallocated. The reason for disposing them promptly is because GC is non-deterministic, and the number of GDI handles is very limited: if you waited for GC to release them, you can exhaust the available GDI pool. Not actually a memory issue.

Comment: Those are not technically *memory* leaks. They leak non-memory resources (well, to be pedantic they will *also* leak some memory but more immediately they leak non-memory unmanaged resources: GDI+ handles).

Comment: @KonradRudolph even then it isn't really a "leak" as such, unless you deliberately sabotage it by calling `SuppressFinalize` - it would *eventually* get released. The fun question is: "which runs out first? memory or handles?"