# repeated call of new Bitmap() - running out of space?

Tags: c#, .net

In a loop, I'm repeatedly doing this:

```
 for (int r=1;r<100;r++)
 {
     for (int c=1;c<100;c++)
     {
          Bitmap b = new Bitmap(
              GetResourceStream("myapp.res.icon.png",
              System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

          grid.SetCellImage(r, c, b);
     }
 }
```

The Bitmap is a small icon (16x16 Pixels).  But after a while I get "Invalid Parameter".

Can it be that repeated calling of this procedure fills up the memory? I have somehow assumed that this statement just delivers a pointer to the Bitmap in the resources, but it seems that it ACTUALLY CREATES A COPY of a Bitmap every time, is that true?

Comment: do not just paste code like that without showing the entire Method and or Event where the code resides.. also post all relevant code.. if you have a `repeated call of new Bitmap()` then show where the repeated call is being made.. it appears that you have a single call here only if you want you can use the following to dispose of `b` `GC.Collect(); and GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();`

Comment: This will create a new bitmap.

Comment: You need to dispose of the bitmap when you're done with it - `Bitmap` is an unmanaged resource (wrapped in a managed type) and you must release it when you don't need it anymore.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Continuous creation of bitmaps leads to memory leak](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918518/continuous-creation-of-bitmaps-leads-to-memory-leak)

Comment: Well, `b` is assigned to a cell's icon of a grid, and then `b` is disposed. But I understand the problem now. This way, I am creating thousands of copies of the Bitmap in memory, and every single copy is assigned to a single cell. I could also create just one single icon, and put the reference to each cell.

Comment: @CodeCaster I edited the question, should be clearer now. I wrongly assumed that the resource already resides in memory, and that `GetBitmap()` only retrieves a pointer to this area. But actually, it seems to create a MEMORY COPY every time.

Comment: @xxbbcc Not really a duplicate, because in my case, I am retrieving the bitmap from a resource in the EXE file. I had assumed that the resource is loaded during startup of the EXE into memory, and that GetBitmap() just returns a pointer, but this assumption was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It creates new object from your stream. What is worse it allocates native resources, than you have to dispose it if you don't need it. To use copy of image simply copy the bitmap object reference:

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(
    GetResourceStream("myapp.res.icon.png",
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
var b2 = b;
var b3 = b;
```

Comment: Yes, indeed, that's the solution. What means "native resources"? I can faintly remember that in early windows versions there was a restricted memory area for resources, but is this still true for Windows 8 ?

Comment: native resource is allocated by GDI+

Answer (score 1):

As the class `Bitmap` is derived from `Image`, it implements `IDisposable`. Consequently, you need to dispose the `Bitmap` when it is no longer needed, which can be done via an explicit call to `Dispose`, but the preferred way is using the `using` keyword if possible.